# Linear algebra confusion T/F

Tags: linear-algebra

TRUE or FALSE?

For any line $l$ through the origin in $R^2$, if $P:R^2\to R^2$ is an orthogonal projection onto $l$,

then $P^2=P$.

There exists a $3 × 4$ matrix $A$ of rank $2$ such that $\ker(A)$ contains the vector $v=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$
 and $\mathrm{image}(A)$ contains the vector $w=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$.

I'm studying for an exam and these two questions came up. For the first, I'm getting confused about what $P^2$ means. I'm trying to come up with an example matrix for the latter, but nothing is working yet.

Comment: $P^2$ means $P$ composed with itself: $P\circ P$. For the second, remember that it is very easy to get linear transformations that do what you want on specific vectors: find a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ that includes $(1,1,1,1)^T$, map that to zero, and the rest to $(1,1,1)^T$. Then figure out what the corresponding matrix will be.

Comment: Okay, so if l is orthogonally projected upon, then the line projecting onto l will also be in R^2, which would mean the statement is True?

Answer (score 1):

I think, it would first be best to think about this intuitively.

If we project $X$ onto $L$ then we get a vector with direction $L.$  If we run our projection operation on a vector with direction L, it does nothing.

$P^2 = P$

If we get a little bit more concrete.

$PX = \frac {X\cdot L}{\|L\|^2} L\\
P^2X = P(\frac {X\cdot L}{\|L\|^2} L)\\$

$\frac {X\cdot L}{\|L\|^2}$ is a scalar and can be pulled outside

$P^2X = \frac {X\cdot L}{\|L\|^2} PL = \frac {X\cdot L}{\|L\|^2} \frac {L\cdot L}{\|L\|^2} L = \frac {X\cdot L}{\|L\|^2} L$

Taking it down one more level.

$X = (x,y), L = (a,b)\\
PX = (\frac {ax + by}{a^2+b^2} a, \frac {ax + by}{a^2+b^2} b) $

If we want a matrix representation $P = \frac {1}{a^2 + b^2}\begin{bmatrix} a^2 & ab\\ab&b^2 \end{bmatrix}$

And indeed $P^2 = P$

As for the second question

$\begin{bmatrix} 
1&-1&1&-1\\
1&1&-1&-1\\
1&0&0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$

The image is spaned by, $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

Rank is 2

The kernel is spaned by $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ is in the span

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want $\ker(A) \supseteq \operatorname{span}\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)^\top\}$ (i.e. a single vector) and $\operatorname{span}\{w_1,\dots,w_m\} \subseteq\operatorname{im}(A)$ with $m < n$. Then you can make the first $m$ columns of $A$, $w_1,\dots,w_m$ (so they are in the image) and then if $w_{m+1}, \dots, w_n$ are the remaining columns (to be chosen), they must satisfy $$A(a_1,\dots,a_n)^\top = a_1w_1 + \dots + a_nw_n = 0.$$

To arrange this, you can let $w_{m+1},\dots,w_{n-1}$ be whatever you want, and then simply set $$w_n = -\frac{1}{a_n}\left(a_1w_1 + \dots + a_{n-1}w_{n-1}\right).$$

So for your example, $A = (w,-w,0,0)$ or $A = (w,w,w,-3w)$ or $A = (w,-w,w,-w)$ are all examples with $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 1$. For rank 2, we can let $w'$ be any vector not in the span of $w$ and take $A = (w,w',-w,-w')$ or maybe $A = (w,w',0,-w - w')$.

Some questions to think about:

1. How do we make this work if $a_n = 0$?
2. How does this calculation change if we require the kernel and image to be **equal** to the given spans (rather than containing them). Also what does rank-nullity imply about the size of the inputs in this case?
3. How do we deal with multiple vectors in the kernel. E.g. $\operatorname{im}(A) = \operatorname{span}\{w_1, w_2\}$ and $\ker(A) = \operatorname{span}\{(1,1,1,1)^\top, (1,2,3,4)^T\}$?

Comment: For your examples of A, the rank would be 3 instead of 2 would it not?

Comment: @JohnBuzzi Rank 1, actually (the column space is just span(w)). I didn't notice the rank condition. In that case, you simply find a vector that isn't a multiple of w to use as a column. I will update my answer.